# No passwd entry for user 'postgres' error

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup Postgres on Ubuntu 14.04 without success. After running

> sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev

and

> sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib

I've managed to install the packages successfully. However upon executing **sudo su - postgres**,  I'm receiving the following error:

> No passwd entry for user 'postgres'

It seems like the installation did not create the user postgres as it is not in the /etc/passwd file. Reinstalling the package does not resolve the issue. How can I add the required postgres user?

Answer (score 22):

It sounds like you want the PostgreSQL *server*:

```
apt-get install postgresql-server
```

Also, you never need to use `sudo su - postgres`. Just:

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

to get an interactive shell, or

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

(or whatever) to run a command.

Answer (score 12):

I've solved the issue by purging and re-installing the packages, i.e.

> sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql*
>
> sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib